# Contract : opcodes FAILWITH / FAIL - gas usage

Tags: contract, gas

If a contract gets to the point where it fails. What is the process in terms of gas usage?

- Storage gas (new storage until failure) : reverted
  Gas usage (used until failure) : reverted
  Gas fee : paid
- Storage gas (new storage until failure) : paid
  Gas usage (used until failure) : reverted
  Gas fee : paid
- Storage gas (new storage until failure) : paid
  Gas usage (used until failure) : paid
  Gas fee : paid